# ESB proxy service

Tags: wso2-esb

We have created the ESB proxy service, in that we are calling External Webservice.

Whenever External Webservice is down we need to redeploy our ESB proxy service, please  provide the solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Endpoint suspension is active.
Just set the Error codes to -1 in the EndpointSuspendState property and see.

Comment: Thank you very much your advise we will try for the same